When is api:// prefix required in scopes for Microsoft Azure Identity application access?
I was using scope in following format in my code:
api://GUID/.default

Then something changed and i started to receive failed authorization responses from HTTP api, according to my experience I have tried and removed api:// prefix and it worked. Can someone explain me when api:// is required? I am trying to find changes between app reg that needs this prefix and app reg where this api:// should be omitted but without success.

Can you add snapshots of what are you trying and error are you getting?


Note that: The audience value is controlled by the accesstokenacceptedversion in the manifest file of the Microsoft Entra ID application.

I created a Microsoft Entra ID application, and the manifest looks like below:

I generated access token and the aud is api://xxx and ver is 1.0:
Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback
Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: api://xxx/.default



Now I updated manifest like below:
"acceptMappedClaims": true,
"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2,


In this scenario you can avoid passing api://  prefix as the aud will be ClientID and ver 2.0:
Passed scope as ClientID/ScopeName

Reference:
oauth 2.0 - Azure Active Directory Token Has Incorrect Audience - Stack Overflow by juunas
